# Data.Text vs Data.ByteString.Char8

Tags: haskell, text, bytestring

Can anyone explain the pros and cons to using `Data.Text`and `Data.ByteString.Char8` data types? Does working with ASCII-only text change these pros and cons? Do their lazy variants change the story as well?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Data.ByteString.Char8` provides functions to treat `ByteString` values as sequences of 8-bit ASCII characters, while `Data.Text` is an independent type supporting the entirety of Unicode.

`ByteString` and `Text` are essentially the same, as far as representation goes — strict, unboxed arrays with lazy variants based on lists of strict chunks. The main difference is that `ByteString` stores octets (i.e. `Word8`s), while `Text` stores `Char`s, encoded in UTF-16.

If you're working with ASCII-only text, then using `Data.ByteString.Char8` will probably be faster than `Text`, and use less memory; however, you should ask yourself whether you're *really* sure that you're only ever going to work with ASCII. Basically, in 99% of cases, using `Data.ByteString.Char8` over `Text` is a speed hack — octets *aren't* characters, and any Haskeller can agree that using the *correct* type should be prioritised over raw, bare-metal speed. You should usually only consider it if you've profiled the program and it's a bottleneck. `Text` is well-optimised, and the difference will probably be negligible in most cases.

Of course, there are non-speed-related situations in which `Data.ByteString.Char8` is warranted. Consider a file containing data that is essentially binary, not text, but separated into lines; using [`lines`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:lines) is completely reasonable. Additionally, it's entirely conceivable that an integer might be encoded in ASCII decimal in the context of a binary format; using [`readInt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:readInt) would make perfect sense in that case.

So, basically:

1. `Data.ByteString.Char8`: For pure ASCII situations where performance is paramount, and to handle "almost-binary" data that has some ASCII components.
2. `Data.Text`: Text, including *any* situation where there's the slightest possibility of something other than ASCII being used.

Comment: I can guarantee there will be ASCII-only text, as my program processes very specific computer generated C files. I'll try both out in any case.

Comment: I would probably go for `Data.ByteString.Char8`, then, as you'll essentially be dealing with a binary format that only *resembles* text. (I'd also recommend checking out [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec) for parsing the files.)

Comment: You also mention that Text encodes as UTF-16 and ByteString as an octet. Does this in general impact memory usage? My application is a code rewriter, and as it is, it uses enormous amounts of memory that I can trace to using String. I already intern my strings, so any improvement would be welcome. This is why I want to change data types.

Comment: @trinithis: Well, if your data is all ASCII, then `Text` will encode each character as two bytes, but `ByteString` will encode them as one. If you're currently using `String`, though, I wouldn't worry too much about it; `String` has *huge* overhead (5 words per character(!)), far more than the other two. See [this summary of memory footprints](http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/06/memory-footprints-of-some-common-data.html).

Comment: @trinithis: Though, of course, you should bear in mind that `String` benefits from sharing, while `ByteString` and `Text`, as unboxed arrays, don't; however, `ByteString` and `Text` both take substrings without copying, and they're just so much smaller to start with that you'd have to try pretty hard to make that disadvantage matter.